# Trying to avoid g++ installed in my image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim as builder

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --prefix=/install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /install /usr/local
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5004

CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

The one of my libraries ( I need PyStan library without the possibility of considering other alternatives) needs a C++ compiler to be installed (not to run) so I have `g++` which causes the image size increase  to 1.4GB .

I tried looking for other alternatives such as musl-gcc or llvm-g++ but none of them seem to be available under my python image.

Is there any workaround to reduce the image weight without needing to install g++?

Comment: Does the library need the compiler to work or just to be installed? Have you tried removing g++ after the installation?

Comment: Why not just remove g++ from the image and install it manually after the image download is complete?

Comment: If you remove the g++ afterwards, you need to be careful though. Just removing g++ in another step will not make the final image smaller, you either need to remove it in the same step where you install it, or make a multistage build (which is probably cleaner).
https://pythonspeed.com/articles/smaller-python-docker-images/

Comment: @FlyingTeller I need PyStan library, which does need a C++ compiler to be installed.

Comment: Just for lulz, what about tcc? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler

Comment: 1. You are already using Docker [multi-stage](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) build to decrease size. Final image size should be like `python:3.8-slim`'s size + `/install` folder size. Do you want to decrease size even for `builder`? 2. If `musl-gcc` is acceptable for you, you may try to use `python:3.8-alpine` (instead of Debian based `3.8-slim`). Alpine distribution is using `musl` library instead of Debian's `glibc`. But you must change `apt-get` command to `apk` supported in Alpine

Answer (score 4):

As commented, switching to an [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine-based) image can lead to a more lightweight Docker image, but you would need to replace Debian's `apt-get` commands with [`apk add`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Package_Keeper) commands.

Do remember that while Alpine images are generally smaller, they can sometimes introduce compatibility issues due to the use of [`musl`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/armhf/musl) instead of [`glibc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). However, if your application and its dependencies are compatible with `musl`, then using an Alpine-based image is a good way to reduce the Docker image size.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine as builder

RUN apk add --no-cache g++ && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir --prefix=/install -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /install /usr/local
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5004

CMD ["python", "server.py"]
```

---

A simpler approach is to add at minimum a cleanup step: In the builder stage, you could clean up unnecessary package manager files to ensure that they do not add to the final size.

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y g++ && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir --prefix=/install -r requirements.txt && \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove g++ && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Be careful with this approach if your app requires `g++` to run as well, as the cleanup stage would remove it.

---

The extreme option would be to use a [scratch image](https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch) for the final layer(!)

After compiling the dependencies, you could use a 'scratch' image and copy only the absolutely necessary binaries and libraries. However, it is tricky to set up and might not be suitable for all applications.